# Special characters breaking textbox submission

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

Currently dealing with a bug if a user submits a special character into a textbox like '/' or '&' the information submits and displays on their profile page but on page reload all input boxes are empty and the user cannot submit any more changes. This is after a page refresh, all the fields I just filled out are now blank, and trying to submit 'test' into the bio i get this console error:

[image]

Here's the form html:

```
<form class="login-signup-form">
    <label for="display-name">Display Name</label>
    <input id="display-name" name="display-name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
    <label for="twitter-link">Twitter link</label>
    <input id="twitter-link" name="twitter-link" type="url" placeholder="https://">
    <label for="instagram-link">Instagram link</label>
    <input id="instagram-link" name="instagram-link" type="url" placeholder="https://">
    <label for="youtube-link">YouTube link</label>
    <input id="youtube-link" name="youtube-link" type="url" placeholder="https://">
    <label for="web-link">Website</label>
    <input id="web-link" name="web-link" type="url" placeholder="https://">
    <label for="artist-bio">Bio</label>
    <textarea id="artist-bio" name="artist-bio" type="text" rows="5" maxlength="250" placeholder="Share what you want (Max: 250 characters)"></textarea>
    <hr />
    <label for="allow-collaboration">Allow collaboration?</label>
    <input id="allow-collaboration" name="allow-collaboration" type="checkbox">
    <h5>Checking the box will display your email address on your Creator page. This indicates your interest in collaborating with other Unearth creators.</h5>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitAccountInfo();">
</form>
```

The respective Jquery that loads the data into the input fields and update fields:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    setFormValues();
});
function setFormValues()
{
    if("@(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.AccountInfo.ImageURL))" == "True")
    {
        $("#profile-image").attr("src", "@Model.AccountInfo.ImageURL");
    }
    if("@(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.AccountInfo.DisplayName))" == "True")
    {
        $("#display-name").val("@Html.Raw(Model.AccountInfo.DisplayName)");
    }
    if("@(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.AspNetUser.Email))" == "True")
    {
        $("#email").val("@Html.Raw(Model.AspNetUser.Email)");
    }
    if("@(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.AccountInfo.TwitterURL))" == "True")
    {
        $("#twitter-link").val("@Model.AccountInfo.TwitterURL");
    }
    if("@(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.AccountInfo.InstagramURL))" == "True")
    {
            $("#instagram-link").val("@Model.AccountInfo.InstagramURL");
    }
    if("@(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.AccountInfo.YouTubeURL))" == "True")
    {
        $("#youtube-link").val("@Model.AccountInfo.YouTubeURL");
    }
    if("@(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.AccountInfo.WebURL))" == "True")
    {
        $("#web-link").val("@Model.AccountInfo.WebURL");
    }
    if("@(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.AccountInfo.Bio))" == "True")
    {
        $("#artist-bio").html("@Model.AccountInfo.Bio").text();
    }
    if("@(Model.AccountInfo.AllowCollaborationFL.HasValue ? Model.AccountInfo.AllowCollaborationFL.Value : false)" == "True")
    {
        $("#allow-collaboration").prop("checked", true);
    }
}

    function updateAspNetUserEmail()
{
    var aspNetUser = new Object();
    aspNetUser.Email = $("#email").val();
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "@Url.Content("~/Account/SubmitEmailInfo/")",
        data: JSON.stringify(aspNetUser),
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data == true)
            {
                location.reload(true);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            //TODO: Indicate Error
        }
        });
}

function submitAccountInfo()
{
    var accountInfo = new Object();
    accountInfo.ImageURL = $("#profile-image").attr("src");
    accountInfo.DisplayName = $("#display-name").val();
    //accountInfo.Email = $("#email").val();
    accountInfo.TwitterURL = $("#twitter-link").val();
    accountInfo.InstagramURL = $("#instagram-link").val();
    accountInfo.YouTubeURL = $("#youtube-link").val();
    accountInfo.WebURL = $("#web-link").val();
    accountInfo.Bio = $("#artist-bio").val();
    accountInfo.AllowCollaborationFL = $("#allow-collaboration").is(":checked");
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "@Url.Content("~/Account/SubmitAccountInfo/")",
        data: JSON.stringify(accountInfo),
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data == true)
            {
                updateAspNetUserEmail();
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            //TODO: Indicate Error
        }
        });
}
```

And lastly, here's my accountcontroller with the Jsonsubmits:

```
public JsonResult SubmitEmailInfo(AspNetUser aspNetUser)
{
    try
    {
        var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        aspNetUser.Id = userID;
        var _aspNetUser = EntityDataAccess.GetAspNetUserByID(userID);
        if (_aspNetUser == null)
        {
            aspNetUser = EntityDataAccess.InsertEmailInfo(aspNetUser);
        }
        else
        {
            aspNetUser.Id = _aspNetUser.Id;
            aspNetUser.EmailConfirmed = _aspNetUser.EmailConfirmed;
            aspNetUser.PasswordHash = _aspNetUser.PasswordHash;
            aspNetUser.SecurityStamp = _aspNetUser.SecurityStamp;
            aspNetUser.PhoneNumber = _aspNetUser.PhoneNumber;
            aspNetUser.PhoneNumberConfirmed = _aspNetUser.PhoneNumberConfirmed;
            aspNetUser.TwoFactorEnabled = _aspNetUser.TwoFactorEnabled;
            aspNetUser.LockoutEnabled = _aspNetUser.LockoutEnabled;
            aspNetUser.LockoutEndDateUtc = _aspNetUser.LockoutEndDateUtc;
            aspNetUser.AccessFailedCount = _aspNetUser.AccessFailedCount;
            aspNetUser.UserName = _aspNetUser.UserName;
            aspNetUser = EntityDataAccess.UpdateEmailInfo(aspNetUser);
        }
        return Json(true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(ex);
    }
}

public JsonResult SubmitAccountInfo(AccountInfo accountInfo)
{
    try
    {
        var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        accountInfo.UserID = userID;
        var _accountInfo = EntityDataAccess.GetAccountInfoByUserID(userID);
        if(_accountInfo == null)
        {
            accountInfo = EntityDataAccess.InsertAccountInfo(accountInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            accountInfo.AccountInfoID = _accountInfo.AccountInfoID;
            accountInfo.CreatorFL = _accountInfo.CreatorFL;
            accountInfo.NeedsVerificationFL = _accountInfo.NeedsVerificationFL;
            accountInfo.VerifiedFL = _accountInfo.VerifiedFL;
            accountInfo.AdminFL = _accountInfo.AdminFL;
            accountInfo = EntityDataAccess.UpdateAccountInfo(accountInfo);
        }
        var algoliaArtistModel = Tools.BuildAlgoliaArtistModel(accountInfo);
        var artistIndexHelper = HttpContext.Application.Get("ArtistIndexHelper") as IndexHelper<ArtistAlgoliaModel>;
        artistIndexHelper.SaveObjectAsync(algoliaArtistModel);
        var algoliaSongModels = Tools.BuildAlgoliaSongModels(accountInfo);
        var songIndexHelper = HttpContext.Application.Get("SongIndexHelper") as IndexHelper<SongAlgoliaModel>;
        songIndexHelper.SaveObjectsAsync(algoliaSongModels);
        return Json(true);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mcve].

Comment: @Jordan you should use jQuery Encode and Decode technique. It will convert special characters in `HTML` entities. See link here [HTML Encode Decode](http://jsbin.com/ejuru/416/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @Sefe see i get complaints here about not posting all the relevant code, and this is everything that fires when an account page is loaded/submitted..

Comment: @MethodMan yes but this is only after submitting an account info with a special character, I do not see this if submitting normal text characters and everything submits just fine

Comment: I was just wondering.. because I can see that in the Image you posted.. disregard my earlier comment then

Comment: @MethodMan no problem :) the special characters I guess just stop the js from loading all the way down so it doesn't get referenced...I assume

Comment: @MdAman I think I do that for my `$('#artist-bio')` already? shouldn't what I do prevent that issue?

Comment: Use code `<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
var message = 'Message is : @Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(ViewBag.Message)';
$("#divmsg").html(message);
});
</script>` or check this link [Encode or Decode](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/html-encoding-in-mvc/)

Comment: @MdAman thanks so far, just i need to replace `divmsg` with `artist-bio` correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this for every input you have

```
   <script>
      function escapeHtml(text) {
       return text
      .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
      .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
      .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
      .replace(/"/g, "``")
      .replace(/'/g, "`");
    }
      var displayname = document.getElementById("display-name").value;
      displayname = escapeHtml(displayname);
      /* repeat for every input */
    </script>
```

Comment: This is probably going to be my correct answer choice, however what about dealing with forward slashes? That one breaks my site as well

Comment: look at this page https://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm , here you have every html code you want.

Comment: also, check this, it's more detailed   https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax Toolkit
 Example,

```
 <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

 <cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender_txtName" runat="server"
                                  Enabled="True" FilterType="LowercaseLetters,UppercaseLetters,Custom" FilterMode="InvalidChars"
                                  InvalidChars="1234567890<>'" TargetControlID="txtName">
</cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
```